# Systray Icons missing after App Crash

Tags: 14.04, icons, skype, system-tray

After installing Alarm Clock (`alarm-clock`) from the Software Center, the program immediately crashed and made the icons in my systray disapear except for Power, Sound, Time/Date, and the Gear.

I tried logging off, rebooting, removing the program, and nothing has brought my icons back.
I know they are still running up there, because i got Skype setup to autostart and it had an icon up there running before I installed the Alarm Clock program.

Is there anything I can do to get my icons back, or do i need to reinstall the OS?
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1

Answer (score 1):

Well after looking around a bit and trying different things, i tried this and it fixed the problem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing, the first thing I come to think of is that some packages were removed. Hence I would start with reinstalling *ubuntu-desktop*, to make sure that all packages which should be installed are there.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

*Edit:*

As regards the Skype icon, you may want to try:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

Comment: Just tried it and no difference.

Comment: @pr0ndigy: Ok. I just edited the answer and added another idea.

Comment: I've already used that, and that's how i got the Skype icon to begin with. But now it's just not showing up, along with my network icon.

Comment: @pr0ndigy: Then I'm out of ideas, unfortunately. Hopefully someone else can do better.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking if the appindicator is installed:

```
dpkg-query -l "libappindicator*"
```

output should look like:

> Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
>
> | Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
>
> |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
>
> ||/ Name             Version       Architecture  Description
>
> +++-================-=============-=============-======================================
>
> ii  libappindicator1 12.10.1+13.10 amd64         Application Indicators
>
> ii  libappindicator3 12.10.1+13.10 amd64         Application Indicators

Comment: Please explain: Why do you suggest checking if the appindicator is installed? Please be more specific as to how this answers his question. Also; Welcome to AskUbuntu :)

Comment: Although it was not caused by Alarm Clock, we had a few machines where icons disappeared similiar to OP.  When troubleshooting, we found "libappindicator1" was missing, or "libappindicator1" and "libappindicator3" were different versions.   Installing or reinstalling, and a reboot fixed the problem.   And thank you, I'm hoping to be helpful on AskUbuntu.

Comment: Also, I'm unable to comment on OP's output above (need more rep), but shouldn't both those packages be "amd64"?   Our machines are all 64bit OS, and both pkgs are "amd64".